# How to fix 508 Resource Limit is reached in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, server, hosting

How to fix **508 Resource Limit is reached** in ***PHP MySQL***

- My website is developed in PHP with MySQL and javascript ajax.
- **My website is blocked**,
- how to rectify immediately in this problem, anyone help me quickly
  please.

but am got bellow error,

```
Resource Limit Is Reached

The website is temporarily unable to service your request as it exceeded resource limit. Please try again later.
Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at domain.co.in Port 80
```

- What is concurrent connection
- How to set Maximum concurrent connections to MySQL
- Any solution is available for this problem

Comment: It's not your coding problem. It's about providing server by your Hosting Provider. You should contact your hosting provider, so that they can increase your bandwidth or other settings for you ;)

Comment: my hosting provider ask **set Maximum concurrent limit** but i don't know any idea about **maximum concurrent limit**

Comment: @Raj Please provide your website URL and please tell me if you are hosted on shared hosting.

Comment: I had the same problem on my old hosting. Please provide me the info above.

Comment: Go to MySQL server **Home** page -> Select **status** menu and increase **max. concurrent connections**  15 to 100 and above. that is the problem. if you know how to increase **max. concurrent connections**  means **please** share.

Answer (score 2):

**What are database concurrent connections?**

Concurrent connections are the connections which are made simultaneously to the database.

On shared hosting, there are some limits. Depending on your provider it could oscilate. Every time a visitor enters on your website, then it makes a connection to the database (if the webpage is connected to mysql).

So, if there are some visitors accessing the website at same time, there would be as many db connections as visitors.

*For the most part, hosting providers will say there are limits on connections (without specifying "database"), and it is about HTML processes.*

**How to increase the number of concurrent connections?**

If you have a VPS or dedicated, then you can go to your MySQL server and change `max_concurrent_connections`. If you are on shared hosting most probably you cannot.

**What can I do?**

Your hosting provider will tell you to upgrade to VPS or other more-power plan with is more expensive than a Shared Hosting.

I would not recommend you to buy a VPS yet. I would recommend you to change your hosting provider.

**Please provide your website URL, where are you hosted, which plan, to help you better.**

Answer (score 0):

This is something you'll have to contact your hosting provider about. They've blocked your site because you've reached your maximum bandwidth limit.

Comment: my hosting provider ask **set Maximum concurrent limit**  but i don't know any idea about **maximum concurrent limit**  any MySQL queries are available to **increase maximum concurrent limit**

Comment: Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at domain.co.in Port 80

That's the relevant part of the question that lead me to it being a bandwidth issue.