# Randomly getting 500/5xx error on php apache hosting

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-500

I have a blog-site on php, wordpress and sometimes I getting 5xx errors in Google Search Console. [image: Random 5xx error on Google Search Console] There was no logging errors in wordpress logs, so I opened logs file that was in root folder of hosting provider called *sampledomain.com*.error.log.4 and I saw this:

```
[Wed May 11 03:46:26.062418 2022] [fcgid:emerg] [pid 19725:tid 139629311256320] (22)Invalid argument: [client xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] mod_fcgid: can't lock process table in pid 19725

2022/05/11 03:46:26 [error] 19562#19562: *16934665 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: sampledomain.com, request: "GET /article/sport/2177/prezident-urala-ya-by-rpl-dazhe-do-20-komand-rasshiril HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/article/sport/2177/prezident-urala-ya-by-rpl-dazhe-do-20-komand-rasshiril", host: "sampledomain.com"

[Wed May 11 22:01:36.842440 2022] [fcgid:emerg] [pid 19979:tid 139629328041728] (22)Invalid argument: [client yyy.yyy.yyy.yy:yyyyy] mod_fcgid: can't lock process table in pid 19979

2022/05/11 22:01:36 [error] 3103#3103: *18671977 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: yyy.yyy.yyy.yy, server: sampledomain.com, request: "GET /article/sport/962/poyavilos-video-parallelnogo-chetvernogo-tulupa-valievoj-i-kondratyuka HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/article/sport/962/poyavilos-video-parallelnogo-chetvernogo-tulupa-valievoj-i-kondratyuka", host: "sampledomain.com"
```

This error appears randomly, but sometimes at the most inopportune moment, like in Google Crawl bot. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

*I am new to Apache and Web. I only know php and js, I didn't really understand http servers.*

Comment: [http status code 5XX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#server_error_responses) usually signify **something is wrong** on the server. it can be internal error due to code or configuration which shows status code 500. if you are using proxy or cdn 502 can also fire if the proxied server unavailable. you can also have 508 due to [resource limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30931749/4648586) (especially prevalent in shared hosting). so, narrowing down the exact 5XX status code you get is the best action you should take now.

Comment: based on your log, it seems you have fastcgi (may cause 500) and a reverse proxy (may cause 502). you should check whether the target of reverse proxy capable of serving that particular page properly in timely manner.

Answer (score 1):

By looking into logs it apears to be issue related to FCGID.

*[Wed May 11 03:46:26.062418 2022] [fcgid:emerg] [pid 19725:tid 139629311256320] (22)Invalid argument: [client xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] mod_fcgid: can't lock process table in pid 19725

Alternatively, you could switch away from FCGID, and use CGI instead. You can change that by going into Server Configuration and changing the PHP Execution mode from FCGID to CGI.

Comment: This can be helpfull if I had my own vds/vps but I only have a webhosting, that allows me to run only as fastCGI apache